# Block all traffic but on specific ports for VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, iptables

I would like to block traffic to a VM running on my machine except for certain ports.  I added some rules to virtual bridge to accept traffic on port 80 in the filter table in the FORWARD chain, since the virtual bridge is set up to forward traffic from the VMs.

I wrote the following:

`sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -o [bridge_iface] -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i [bridge_iface] -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -o [bridge_iface] -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i [bridge_iface] -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP`

When I connect tot he vm on the bridge i can't connect to an external web site.  If i remove the last line, of course, everything works but everything is open too.  So that's not quite right.

Comment: What interface are you specifying as `[bridge_iface]` for each rule? Try adding some ad-hoc logging rules or monitor which counters are incremented when you test for connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to drop the traffic TO your VM, why are you filtering also the other direction, do you really want to prevent your VM from accessing the internet?

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o [bridge_iface] -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -o [bridge_iface] -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -o [bridge_iface] -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Please note: DNS is using mostly UDP, not TCP, so you should filter for UDP.

The whole idea about my setup: you should ALLOW your computer to forward anything, only DROP connections to a specific interface by default, and open the specific ports also on thad device.

I suspect that you're using port forwarding on incoming connections on port 80 and 53 to be served by the VM, am i correct ?
If you want to deny your VM from accessing the internet, except for the 2 ports we just set up, you have to change -o to -i in the script.